# jQuery detect and validate an URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's imagine I have this text:

`Hi, my name is Pablo and my home page is http://zad0xsis.net`

How can I detect and validate the URL so it automatically wraps it into `<a href="the detected url">the detected url</a>`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
var s = 'Hi, my name is Pablo and my home page is http://zad0xsis.net';
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
s = s.replace(exp,"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>"); 
alert(s);
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rsf6G/).

Answer (score 0):

Can also try the jquery linkify plugin @ http://code.google.com/p/jquery-linkify/

Easy to use -

```
$('.section').linkify();
```

Pretty much does the same as mentioned by Darin.