# Detect url in textarea with JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, textarea

How to detect (in a textarea or others inputs) if the user has finished to enter a url as Facebook does in its main form please ?

Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705501/jquery-detect-and-validate-an-url) work but only when the user has finished typing and performs an action, eg clicking a button.

I will wish to detect urls throughout the entry, eg run a check on the word that has been typed after each space.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The identification of URLs would be the same, you'd just be binding it to a different event - a key being pressed rather than a button being clicked.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example on how you could do this:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    var url = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;

    $("#textarea").on("keyup", function( e ) {
        var urls, output = "";
        if ( e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 9 && e.keyCode !== 13 && e.keyCode !== 32 && e.keyCode !== 46 ) {
            // Return is backspace, tab, enter, space or delete was not pressed.
            return;
        }

        while ((urls = url.exec(this.value)) !== null) {
            output += urls[0] + ", ";
        }
        console.log("URLS: " + output.substring(0, output.length - 2));
    });
});
```

Of course you would have to bind other events like [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) for it to work properly.

Try the following fiddle and check you console as you type: http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/mXQrc/1/

Answer (score 8):

Look at this: https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl/
- its clean, simple, and provides a preview of the url!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the keypress event, you can view the documentation and an example of how to use it here: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/