# Recognize url in textarea tag and make it clickable

Tags: html, url, textarea, plaintext

I feel this should be easy to do, I just don't know how to start.

I have a textarea where users will be able to add a description for something. Usually users will like to add links to pages such us "http://www.google.com". However, the textarea tag sees it as plain text and not as a link.

How can i solve this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl/ - its clean, simple, and provides a preview of the url!

Credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13819100/4025845)

Comment: Thanks @Unlockedluca will try to do this

Comment: This is a very good library. Note that you have to first give the textarea an ID.