# how to detect url inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

chrome can detect `url` inside a `textarea`
select an url - right click - and you'll see - `go to ...`  
so I hope it is possible similar by clicking inside an url - get the `href` in console
the code below is probably a start but it results in entire body as selection
any idea?

```js
document.onselectionchange = () => {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log(selection.anchorNode);
};
```

```css
#ed{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:50vh;
padding:9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='ed'>
lorem ipsum
https://google.com
dolor sit
</textarea>
```

Comment: You can use regex? -- [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/NIRbbR/1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093350/detect-url-in-textarea-with-js-or-jquery

Comment: @AribYousuf - no, your link is about detect url while typing

Comment: @Zak - regex would be ok if the textarea contains only one single url. But in case there is more of them - regex cannot know which of them is clicked or selected

Comment: I was suggesting something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Vap7C/15/) With a "test" afterward to see IF it's a URL with `regex` .. If it is .. Do --

Comment: Of course you'll have to modify it to use the textarea `val()` etc etc .. But the bones of what need to be done are there I think ..

Comment: @Zak - I tried already. Problem - all the stuff about ranges works outside the textarea - paragraph in your example - but not inside a textarea.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be a `textarea` ?  Can it be a `<p>` with `contentEditable="true"` ?  `<p contentEditable="true">` Essentially it WORKS like a textarea at that point ..

Comment: @Zak - yes, this is possible with editable div, but editable div has a much more unsolved problems like this, believe me

Comment: [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/59gysf7q/) Demonstrates my thoughts ..  The only caviat is the "line break" is not "seen" as a line break inside a `<p>` tag .. Maybe `pre` CSS or something like that .. There is a workaround ..

Comment: @Zak - place some links, some paragraphs and  some line breaks inside your fiddle. Then delete some of them. And then check its html. You'll see a real mess, unpossible to control

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to:

1. Store the cursor selection
2. Use regex or a string comparison method to verify it's a URL
3. Use `window.location.href = identifiedUrlString`

Comment: question is about `href`  - it is a string - not a link or hyperlink. thanks anyway

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: problem is to get a selection comparable with the url syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script>
  function isURL(value){
   var regex = /https?:\/\/[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*/g;
   if(regex.test(value))
   {
     console.log(value);
   }
  }
 document.onselectionchange = () => {
    var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    isURL(text);
};
</script>
```

Comment: yes, this is the way in case you have a comparable string clicked or selected. But here is entire body as a string. And plus, the textarea can contain more then one urls. How to know which of them is clicked or selected? That's crucial